# Distorted objects in Azure Kinect camera

Tags: azure, kinect, depth, azurekinect

we have a problem when trying to use kinect for estimating shape and position of an object due to distortion in PointCloud data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fogTh.jpg)

at the image above u can see plastic box of size 10x10x10 cm but in pointcloud there is a distortion of one of the sides.

another example contains same plastic box and a cardboard box, distortion is very similar:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiI6M.jpg)

what is the source of this issue?